# Sharing object between different object

Tags: c#, sharing

I am having a situation that I have a common reference object that is being pass around as parameter to different operation object.  It makes the code very messy to pass it around.
Is there anyway to make it like a reference to every operation (like a session)?   However, it is just a core code library.  Using static class is not the solution.

Thanks

Comment: why isn't static class the solution is it is just a core code library?

Comment: You should give details about your use case (examples).

Comment: You could have it as a global property that all your functions can access, or you can make your code less messy. If you want anything better you should maybe post some example code of your exact needs

Comment: The reason is that the library is being used on web and there is a possiblity that multiple user are using it.  Static will have the same copy among user.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 - You can use singletons. They guarantee that there is only one instance of the class in the running code.

Solution 2 - why don't you put the shared reference object as a property of the object with those operations? That way, each operation has access to it. You can do some fancy stuff like if the reference property is null, throw an exception or so.

Comment: I understand .  both IoC and amibent context are baiscally singleton.  My problem will become that it is an application being used by multi user and the object that i am storing is user based info.  singleton will give me the same object among multiple users.

Answer (score 1):

There are two general approaches to this that I know of:

a) Use IoC and a constructor dependency to pass in your shared object. As you mentioned if this object is used in many, many places this pollutes the interface and in many cases adds a lot of clutter.

b) Use an [ambient context](http://www.timjroberts.com/2010/12/the-ambient-context-pattern/): Create a interface based singleton that may be accessed by the classes that need the object instance. Have a setter within the singleton that allows you to override the instance (e.g. for unit testing) so testing the code is still possible.

Comment: I understand .  both IoC and amibent context are baiscally singleton.  My problem will become that it is an application being used by multi user and the object that i am storing is user based info.  singleton will give me the same object among multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Ambient Context Pattern could work for you? http://aabs.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/the-ambient-context-design-pattern-in-net/

Comment: I tried.  It doesn't work for me.  My situation is that I have .net assembly being used by pure asp.  The pattern will then face the static thread situation that data leaking across the site.  I can't use threadstatic and callcontext because it is not quite working in my situation.